# Multiple queries nodejs mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

running the multiple queries  here is the code

```
 module.exports.getAllternaryCat=function(req,res) {


     var output = {};

  connection.query('SELECT * FROM ternary_categories',function(error,results,filelds){
      if(error) throw err;

      async.eachSeries(results,function(data,callback){ // It will be executed one by one
              //Here it will be wait query execute. It will work like synchronous
            //  output.push(data);
                  output['ternaryCategory']= results;
              connection.query('SELECT * FROM secondary_category  where id = '+data.secondary_categoryId,function(error,results1,filelds){
                  if(error) throw err;

                //  output.push(results1)
                output['secondaryCategory']= results1;


                  callback();
              });

              connection.query('SELECT * FROM primary_category  where id = '+data.secondary_categoryId,function(error,results1,filelds){
                  if(error) throw err;

                output['PrimaryCategory']= results1;


              });


      }, function(err, results) {
           res.json({
                    status:true,
                    data:output

                })
      });


  })

}
```

The query for primary category is not returning the results object, only the ternaryCategory, secondaryCategory is returning, not the PrimaryCategory. New to node help me with this. I tried with sync water fall didn't understood.

Comment: What do you mean by not 'coming in', is it undefined, empty, or simply not present in the object?

Comment: No errors . when i run the  app in results object  only the ternaryCategory and secondaryCategory is coming not the primaryCateory.

Comment: Re-read my question and edit your comment please, you literally repeated what you'd said in the original question..

Comment: i am not the getting primarycategory object in "output" object i mean in response ...only  the query results of ternaryCategory and SecondaryCategory is coming

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke the `callback()` function after your second query, not after the first one. That query probably isn't even getting invoked, as per the [documentation](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries).

Also, you seem to be overwriting your object properties, but I'm not going to go into that as I don't know your intentions, just a hint.

I'd also suggest you use a slightly better naming convention, i.e. don't use *results1* for two different queries, you'll end up confusing yourself in the long run.